# Processing batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

Having an issue where I get information from one token but not the other. I am doing a reg query and want to compare the value using GEQ this variable as per following registry DWORD Value:
ValueName: Version
Value Data (Hex):4020000

Here is the command which is still in testing:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set n2=0x4020000

:Query
fOR /f "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\A2C5AA9AEF84B7B4BADF0EA6D2D6F1E8" /v version') DO SET n1=%%B
for /f "tokens=2* delims=x" %%a in ("%n2%") do set "v2=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2* delims=x" %%a in ("%n1%") do set "v1=%%a"
>>"C:\temp\version.txt" echo %v1,%v2%
```

No matter what I cannot output %v1% which is the live value I need to compare against..what am I missing?

Thanks

Mikoyan

Comment: `%v1,%v2%` doesn't look right to me. What should it evaluate to?

Comment: so %v2% shows as 4020000 but I cant get any information from %V1% variable

Comment: Still an `%` sign still to be missing (after _v1_, and before the comma) in the `echo` command. What is the content of `n1` after the 1st `for` loop? or wider, what's the content of the registry value?

Comment: Oh my.......im really sorry about this. I was having one of those days. Apologies for this :$ how can I delete the question, I should really aware you guys with the answer I couldn't see the blatant mistake!